# Terraform Azure Provider 2.x Error: “features”: required field is not set

Tags: azure, terraform, provider

I receive the above error, even though I already have the features block, as per the below code extract, however I continue to receive the error when running terraform plan:

```
provider "azurerm" {
features {}
version = ">=2.0.0"
}
```

I have also tried pinning the provider version with "=2.0.0"; "=2.1.0"; "=2.2.0"; "=2.3.0"; "=2.4.0", and each time deleting the .terraform directory, and doing a fresh init, and plan each time. but still get same error every time

Normally I’ve been using ">=2.0.0" ever since the 2.0 AzureRm Provider got released, and I originally added the features block without issue, but now with this error that tells me there is no features block, when in fact I do have a features block - that’s why I’ve been trying all these different version combinations but without luck.

I’ve also tried all of the above with different versions of terraform.exe (0.12.19; 0.12.21; 0.12.24), also deleting the .terraform directory with each new version.

Error: "features": required field is not set

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you

Tested all the above on Windows 10 v1809

Comment: The follwoing work for me : `provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = var.SUBSCRIPTION_ID
  client_id       = var.SP_CLIENT_ID
  client_secret   = var.SP_CLIENT_SECRET
  tenant_id       = var.SP_TENANT_ID
  version         = "=2.0.0"
  features {}
}`  Terraform version - 0.12.24

In case it's working I'll write an explanation :)

Comment: Thanks - this did help me a little bit. I have managed to get passed the error. I moved the provider block to main.tf, and I had to create a 2nd provider block for the sub I was accessing. It does not work with just one:


`# Azure Provider/s

provider "azurerm" {

  features {}
  
  version  = ">=2.0.0"
  
}

 
provider "azurerm" { 

  features {} 
  
  alias = "cloud_operations"
  
  subscription_id = var.provider_ids.operations
  
  skip_provider_registration = "true"
  
}`


Terraform.exe = 0.12.24

AzureRM Provider = 2.4.0

Comment: So, all good now ?

Comment: yes - thank you for the assistance

Comment: Can I post this as an answer?